# Max length increasing super array made by joining two increasing subarray

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Problem:
Given an array, find two increasing subarrays(say `a` and `b`) such that when joined they produce one increasing array(say `ab`). We need to find max possible length of array `ab`.

For example:
given `array = [2 3 1 2 5 4 5]`

Two sub arrays are  `a = [2 3]`, `b = [4, 5]` and `ab = [2 3 4 5]`
Output: `length(ab) = 4`

Comment: Interesting. Every increasing subarray looks like an interval to me with a start and an end.

Comment: Also a note that an increasing subarray also has multiple increasing subarrays inside of it. So something similar to order statistics tree should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve it using brute force. By brute force I can get all the subarrays and then check if it is increasing. Then I can use a merge array and check if there are overlapping elements. If there are overlapping elements will remove them and store the length.

The time complexity for getting all the subarrays will be `O(n^2)` (I am assuming subarray will maintain the relative order and you do not mean all the subsets). And then will sort the subarrays using a queue and the sorting strategy would be the according to the first element. Then I will check how many can be merged with increasing property(something you use to merge already sorted array).

Then count the strictly increasing arrays after merging.

The other two approaches can be used by dynamic programming(this is same as longest contiguous increasing subarray): ([Look here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-increasing-subarray/))

**First approach:**

```
 public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {            
    if(nums.length == 0) { return 0; }

    int[] dp = new int[nums.length];

    int len = 0;

    for(int n: nums) {

        // Find the position of it in binary tree.
        int pos = Arrays.binarySearch(dp, 0, len, n);

        // Convert the negative position to positive.
        if(pos < 0) { pos = -1*(pos + 1); }

        // assign the value to n
        dp[pos] = n;

        // If the length of the dp grows and becomes equal to the current len
        // assign the output length to that.
        if(pos == len) {
           len++;
        }
    }

    // Return the length.
    return len;
}
```

**Another method:**

```
public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {

    if(nums == null || nums.length == 0) { return 0; }
    int n = nums.length;

    Integer lis[] = new Integer[n]; 
    int max = 0; 

    /* Initialize LIS values for all indexes 
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        lis[i] = 1; 
    }

    /* Compute optimized LIS values in bottom up manner 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ )  {
            if ( nums[i] > nums[j] && lis[i] < lis[j] + 1) {
                lis[i] = lis[j] + 1; 
            }
        } 
    }
    max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(lis));
    return max; 
}
```

Comment: How do you check "how many can be merged with increasing property"? There are n^4 pairs if you simply do brute force.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is of brute force, By brute force I can get all the increasing sub arrays. Then I can use check if there are overlapping elements. If there are overlapping elements will calculate the length after merge and then compare and store the max length.